# Cannot populate jComboBox depending on other ComboBox from postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, netbeans

There are two ComboBoxes "jComboCins1 and jComboCinsM". I want to populate jComboCinsM depending on jComboCins1 from postgresql. Here is the code, no errors but still cannot populate. Thanks in advance for all replies.

```
public class MekleFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        Statement st = null;

    /**
     * Creates new form MekleFrame
     */
    public MekleFrame() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        jTextFielddummy.setVisible(false);



       conn = dbConnection.ConnectDB();
       update_table();
       pop_combo();
    }
private void pop_combo(){

      try {    
        //String cnsCo=jComboCins1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String sql = "SELECT * from cinsdb WHERE sinif= ?";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        //pst.setString(1,cnsCo);
        pst.setString(1,String.valueOf(jComboCins1.getSelectedItem()));
        rs=pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next())
        {
        String cinsad = rs.getString("cinsad");
        jComboCinsM.addItem(cinsad);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing some part like the  declaration of your combobox. Are you sure your while loop is called ? how did you check it?

Comment: So what happens? Did you display the value of the selected Item before doing the SQL query? Did you verify the ResultSet return data from the database? Why would you do a "select *" from the database if you only want data from a single column. Make your SQL efficient by only returning the data you need.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony and camickr for your replies. If i change the SQL Query without "where" and disable pst.setString() i can populate ComboBox. I guess there is someting wrong wit the ResultSet or PreparedStatement. I tried the SQL Query as "SELECT cinsad from cinsdb WHERE sinif= ?", didnt work either. By the way SQL connection and Queries work fine, tested.